# When sending an sms, is every sent sms assigned a unique identifier?

Tags: php, android, sms

I am making an sms application and i am very interested in delivery reports.I want to send an sms using available http gateways for android and i have settled on ozeki smpp gateway android app which can be viewed here http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=785

However i am wondering,when i send an sms then send another one with the same message and the message is sent to exactly the same recepient,how will i know which sms was delivered?.

When sending an sms, is the sms assigned a unique identifier such that i can tell two sms apart by just viewing delivery reports even though the sms are identical in message and recipient?.

Comment: You're wondering if you send duplicate messages something will somehow do *what*?

Comment: No, i have a theory behind my head that maybe the delivery report would contain the unique identifier that message was assigned during send.

Comment: I believe every message does have an id, but if you send the message twice it has two ids. I believe the id contains a timestamp.

Comment: Does the delivery report contain the timestamp that was issued during send?.

Comment: I am not referring to any product.

Comment: presumably you are referring to the delivery report in ozeki smpp gateway android app. I don't know if it has delivery reports at all. You could ask ozeki. They have an email address in the top right hand corner of the web page you linked to.

Comment: Turns out i was right.There is a reference id http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=538